# The property "Visible" of a VBA Frame in excel has no effect, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: excel, vba, properties

I am new to VBA, trying to do some simple things. My code needs to hide a certain frame from the user, but changing the property "visible" to false has no effect, neither manually nor using code.

[image: The Frame stays visible]

What is wrong here?

Comment: The frame will remain visible in the designer, is it still shown at run-time?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Wow, thank you. It does hide at run-time. It seems my code wasn't working and I assumed that manually changing it was also not working, but hadn't tested it at run-time.

Comment: Yep, it was the code, solved it.